# Does gcc (or any other compiler) change (n%2==1) for (n&1==1)?

Tags: gcc

To test if a number is odd or even,
It is my understanding that a test using

```
(n%2==1)
```

Is the same thing as

```
(n&1==1)
```

I assume the first test is faster (please correct me if I'm wrong), but does any compiler recognize this and "correct" it? Does this makes any difference in performance?

Comment: I can't speak with confidence here because I've never tried to look into this, but my instinct tells me, "No."  The reason is that the compiler doesn't "know" that you want to find odd numbers, it just knows that you want the remainder (modulus).

Comment: @DavidHoelzer http://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2009/12/02/gcc-optimizations-for-arithmetic-operations-using-bit-shifts/ would claim differently, I haven't tried it out myself though. I'd be a little bit surprised if any major C/C++ compilers *didn't* do this on the highest optimization settings.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing this as well. I would hope it optimizes something like this, similar to multiplying an integer by 2.

Comment: Some made comments about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110752/what-is-the-correct-way-to-obtain-1n , from them I understand that the they should be *optimized* to the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int i = n & 1;
}
    call    __main
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    andl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret

void main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int i = n % 2;
}
    call    __main
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cltd
    shrl    $31, %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    andl    $1, %eax
    subl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Tried with gcc.exe (GCC) 4.9.2 using `-S -O0`
So it seams that `& 1` to check parity is slightly better.

Comment: Looks good for my gut instinct.  What does it do at  highest optimization?

Comment: You shouldn't use `void main()`, and with enough optimization, the whole body of the function can be optimized out.  You'd do better with `return i;`, but since the compiler can compute the answer at compile time, that won't help either.  So, make sure your calculation depends on user input, such as a command line argument: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int n = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 5; int i = n & 1; return i; }` or equivalent.

Comment: @zerges How a compiler optimizes code when you don't enable optimization is usually not that interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Actually
`(n%2==1)`
is not the same as
`(n&1==1)`
if type of `n` is `signed int`, so the compiler code(gcc 5.1, -Ofast, 64bit):

```
int f(int n)
{
    return (n % 2) == 1;
0:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
2:   c1 e8 1f                shr    $0x1f,%eax
5:   01 c7                   add    %eax,%edi
7:   83 e7 01                and    $0x1,%edi
a:   29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
c:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
e:   83 ff 01                cmp    $0x1,%edi
11:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
}
14:   c3                      retq
```

So main part looks like(pseudo code):

```
 uint64_t edi = eax;
 eax >>= 0x1f;
 edi += eax;
 edi &= 1;
 edi -= eax;
```

But if type of n is "unsigned int" all looks great(gcc 5.1, -Ofast):

```
0000000000000000 <f>:
unsigned char f(unsigned int n)
{
    return (n % 2) == 1;
0:   83 e7 01                and    $0x1,%edi
}
3:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
5:   c3                      retq
```